# can't get fancybox2 to upload to my server

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I've installed FancyBox 2 in a new site I'm building with Dreamweaver cc.

Everything works fine when I preview in my Safari browser. Problem is that when I try to upload the site to my server, the fancy box code won't upload.

I get the following message:

> js:fancy box:source:jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5 - error occurred - An
>   FTP error occurred - cannot put jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5.  Internal
>   data error, possibly because of failure to start the upload.

What would cause this?

Comment: remove `?v=2.1.5` when uploading, it's not part of the file name

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a fancy box or jQuery issue, but rather a Dreamweaver issue.

Dreamweaver has had FTP abnormalities for many years and many versions. I experience this identical error message in DW CC several times a month. Generally deleting the file from the server (if it already exists), restarting the machine, and trying again does the trick.

A pain, indeed. Do like me and submit an error report to Adobe each and every time. I bet I've submitted hundreds over the years. Maybe one day they will do some good.